# Get Request result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

A page

```
<div id="message"></div>

<form id="help_form" name="help_form" onsubmit="return validate_help_form()">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

a script

```
function validate_help_form() {

    if ( ... ) {
            ...
            return false;
    }

    $.ajax({

        url : 'http://localhost:8080/appname/question.action',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(result) {    
            var jsAtt = '${message}';
            console.log(jsAtt);     
            $('#message').text(result);
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Unable to receive result. ' + thrownError);
        },
    });

    return true;

}
```

I have the following in my controller:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "some data here...");
```

The idea is to get request attribute in javascript and update a `message` id in the page but I get the following error in console:

> POST http://localhost:8080/appname/question.action 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

If I doing the same without ajax then `action="question.action"` in the form works. Where is the error?

Comment: You're not sending any parameters in your AJAX request.

Comment: @Barmar but I send request url

Comment: The error is happening on the server, check its error log to see the reason.

Comment: The form doesn't have `method="post"`. Try `type: "GET"` to be like the form.

Comment: @Barmar you were right - error is in on the server and I need to send some parameters in the ajax requst